# Omit Date from LyX Titlepage in KOMA-Script Book

Tags: lyx, titles, koma-script

By default, when using Lyx with the KOMA-Script Book class, the date is shown below the title and author name on the titlepage. I would like to omit the date from the titlepage. Is there a way to accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try to add `\date{}` before calling `\maketitle`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! The ERT method of adding `\date{}` at the beginning of the document does work. Unfortunately, ERT can make the workspace a bit of a mess, so I try to avoid it when possible. This is why I've accepted G.M.'s answer as the solution -- it avoids the need for ERT. A Feldman, you did a lot of work on your answer with the specifics and the screenshots, and I want to thank you for that. To anyone in the future who would prefer to use the ERT method, yours is certainly a very comprehensive answer.

Comment: Not a lot of work.  As a former LyX user I completely understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check Documents > Settings > Suppress default date on front page.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is as simple as adding the "evil red text" `\date{}` to your preamble. To add your ERT place the cursor before your title, Ctrl-l (that's a small "L" not a capital "I") and type `\date{}` into the red box, and that should do it. You can also choose the menu button marked `TeX` or go through your menu, `Insert` then `TeX-Code` to add your TeX. And see related [*A Brief History of ERT*](https://www.lyx.org/news/20000315.php)

A Latex MWE solely for illustration (and not the code LyX uses to produce the same document) is below:

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}

    \title{Hello Cat}
    \author{me} 
    \date{}


  \begin{document}

    \maketitle


    Hello Alice.

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Go to Document>Settings>Document class] and tick suppress default date on front page. I found this out while scouring for a simple way to get this done on this page and thought to share.

Comment: This is already covered in the accepted answer. Perhaps we can take your screen grab and add it to that?